# WebClient.OpenRead download data in chunks

Tags: c#, stream, webclient, chunks

I am trying to download data using a Webclient object in chunks of 5% each. The reason is that I need to report progress for each downloaded chunk.

Here is the code I wrote to do this task:

```
    private void ManageDownloadingByExtractingContentDisposition(WebClient client, Uri uri)
    {
        //Initialize the downloading stream 
        Stream str = client.OpenRead(uri.PathAndQuery);

        WebHeaderCollection whc = client.ResponseHeaders;
        string contentDisposition = whc["Content-Disposition"];
        string contentLength = whc["Content-Length"];
        string fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(contentDisposition.IndexOf("=") +1);

        int totalLength = (Int32.Parse(contentLength));
        int fivePercent = ((totalLength)/10)/2;

        //buffer of 5% of stream
        byte[] fivePercentBuffer = new byte[fivePercent];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            int count;
            //read chunks of 5% and write them to file
            while((count = str.Read(fivePercentBuffer, 0, fivePercent)) > 0);
            {
                fs.Write(fivePercentBuffer, 0, count);
            }
        }
        str.Close();
    }
```

The problem - when it gets to str.Read(), it pauses as much as reading the whole stream, and then count is 0. So the while() doesn't work, even if I specified to read only as much as the fivePercent variable. It just looks like it reads the whole stream in the first try.

How can I make it so that it reads chunks properly?

Thanks,

Andrei

Comment: Register for the WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged event, then call WebClient.DownloadDataAsync(). You can update your progress in the event callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do
{
    count = str.Read(fivePercentBuffer, 0, fivePercent);
    fs.Write(fivePercentBuffer, 0, count);
} while (count > 0);
```

Comment: this works, thanks. can't figure out why it works though. probably because the while is after count is modified.

Answer (score 3):

You have a semi-colon on the end of the line with your while loop.  I was very confused as to why the accepted answer was right, until I noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an exact 5% chunk size, you may want to look into the async download methods such as [DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms144190%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [OpenReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.openreadasync%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

They fire the [DownloadProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event each time new data is downloaded and the progress changes, and the event provides the percentage completion in the event args.

Some example code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri(address);

// Specify a progress notification handler.
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);

client.DownloadDataAsync(uri);

static void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
    Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...", 
        (string)e.UserState, 
        e.BytesReceived, 
        e.TotalBytesToReceive,
        e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the application does not allow for asynchronous downloads. I have to find a way of dealing with reporting progress from a synchronous download.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'the application does not allow for asynchronous downloads'? How does your application prevent this?

Comment: My application needs to download several files and it needs to have them synchronously, one at a time, this is simply a request for the task. Initially to do this I was using webclient.DownloadFile() which is synchronous download, but I need to also do reporting of progress, so I thought of using  webClient.OpenRead() for reporting chunks.

Comment: @Andrei You could try chaining the download requests. Download one file, then once that download completes, call DownloadDataAsync for the next file within the event handler.

Comment: Although I agree with you, and understand what you are saying, and I agree that is the most obvious and easiest solution, the application I work on is at such an advanced level, that switching to async downloads will require a time of development and re-testing that is completely unacceptable by the customer. So that is why I was hoping that there is something wrong in the code I posted that could be made functional.