# Get data chunks when downloading file

Tags: angular, file, download, chunks, angular-httpclient

When I make something like

```
this.http.get('some link which returns a file').subscribe(
    result => console.log(result)
);
```

I will only see result when file is completely downloaded. Is there a way to use this file being partly downloaded? I mean, can I see a set of data chunks while file download is in progress?

I use Angular 6 and NodeJS on back end.

Comment: Did you read https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events?

Comment: No. Progress events only show progress. I want to see the Data. like when u dl the file, u see 1 mb of 10 is already downloaded. So how can i get those 1 mb of data. I want someth like:  this.http.get('some link which returns a file').subscribe(
    result => onchunck(chunk => console.log(chunk.data))
);

Comment: its not a code )) its just to describe the desired result

Comment: Then as far as I'm aware, that's not exposed by the HttpClient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424117/webclient-openread-download-data-in-chunks/7432296 check this answer